# CUPS test page successfully print out result in Blank page

Tags: drivers, printing, epson, cups-lpd

I have setup successfully with Epson linux driver. When I try to print test page, it is resulting in a **blank page** with ***successful*** print status.

The printer is working properly with Google cloud print.

- Already try to change to multiple protocols (IPP, LPD, HTTPS)
- Already try with local file PPD in `/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2/ppds/`
- Already try with some generic printer drivers

Are there any way to debug and get a printer work?

> Ubuntu 16.04, Epson L4160
>
> **Ubuntu Package installed**
>
> printer-driver-escpr, lsb, epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.0.9-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Comment: when I go to the Epson site and type in L4160 it shows an update and the version they offer is epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.0.10-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb and it was released 17th Jan this year; this is the link http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=69228&DSCCHK=1ea2a5d8d920cb08927c8420093739b6fedd8fff see if that helps

Comment: No. It's doesn't help. It is still output in a blank page.

Comment: Ubuntu have a wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems that you could work through; if you open the PRINTERS folder; and hit the F1 key; it opens a trouble-shooting wizard; is it of any use to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printer become function properly when do gunzip and manual change driver file to use directly from the ppd file.

Step

1. Backup ppd file.
2. Unzip ppd.gz file from epson deb package from [download site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)  `sudo gunzip /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2/ppds/Epson/Epson-L4160_Series-epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2.ppd.gz`
3. Open Printer Properties
4. Make and Model > Change...
5. Provide PPD file
6. Select a file from /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2/ppds/Epson/Epson-L4160_Series-epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2.ppd

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I resolved it by deleting line "*ESCPRCompression: 3, 16" in file "Epson-L4160_Series-epson-escpr2-en.ppd".